# MySQL Connection is not available after few minutes of running of INSERTs loop in Python

Tags: python, mysql

I am running a Python "for" loop with Mysql INSERTs (lot of data).

After cca 5 mins of running I am getting the error:

```
raise OperationalError("MySQL Connection not available")
mysql.connector.errors.OperationalError: MySQL Connection not available
```

Cursor settings:
buffered=True
autocommit=False

Tried commit in the loop after each INSERT but without success

The code:

```py
target_mysql_cursor = target_mysql.cursor(buffered=True)

if source_cursor.is_connected() & target_mysql.is_connected():
    print("Connection OK")

    for hour in range(0,23):
        source_mysql_cursor.execute( raw_data_query, (hour, hour))
        result_set = source_mysql_cursor.fetchall()

        for result in result_set:
            result_string = str(result)
            row = result_string.split(",")

            platform_stats_record = (row[0][2:], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4], row[5], row[6], row[7], row[8], row[9], row[10], row[11], row[12], row[13], row[14], row[15], row[16], row[17], row[18][0:8], row[19][0:8])
            print(platform_stats_record)

            target_mysql_cursor.execute(platform_stats_insert_query, platform_stats_record)
```

Comment: what does your code look like?

Comment: @Anentropic: Topic updated (code).

Comment: do you know which connection has dropped, source or target?

Comment: sounds similar: https://stackoverflow.com/q/73800254/202168

Comment: @Anentropic: target.

Comment: I have the impression the solution is probably to catch the error and reconnect as needed

Comment: What about this?                                                                                                con = _mysql.connect(host='localhost', user='dell-pc', passwd='', db='test',
          connect_timeout=1000)

Comment: try it I guess, making it longer seems like it should help https://stackoverflow.com/a/16192765/202168 shows how to query the current value

Comment: @Anentropic: Even with "connect_timeout=28800". Correction: the SOURCE connection dropped.  Error: source_mysql_cursor = stats_mysql.cursor(buffered=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 1344, in cursor
    raise OperationalError("MySQL Connection not available")
mysql.connector.errors.OperationalError: MySQL Connection not available

Comment: it does make more sense that the source connection dropped. Possibly the relevant timeout config is this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/50763544/202168 when paging through query results on a cursor ‍♂️

Comment: @Anentropic: yes, but 'max_execution_time' is set to '0' on the source server.

Comment: This doc also mentions trying to increase net_read_timeout:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/error-lost-connection.html